# Generating a very large matrix of string combinations using combn() and bigmemory package

Tags: r, combinatorics, bigdata

I have a vector x of 1,344 unique strings. I want to generate a matrix that gives me all possible groups of three values, regardless of order, and export that to a csv.

I'm running R on EC2 on a m1.large instance w 64bit Ubuntu. When using combn(x, 3) I get an out of memory error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.0 Gb
```

The size of the resulting matrix is C1344,3 = 403,716,544 rows and three columns - which is the transpose of the result of combn() function.

I thought of using the bigmemory package to create a file backed big.matrix so I can then assign the results of the combn() function. I can create a preallocated big matrix:

```
library(bigmemory)
x <- as.character(1:1344)
combos <- 403716544
test <- filebacked.big.matrix(nrow = combos, ncol = 3, 
        init = 0, backingfile = "test.matrix")
```

But when I try to allocate the values `test <- combn(x, 3)` I still get the same: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.0 Gb`

I even tried coercing the result of `combn(x,3)` but I think that because the combn() function is returning an error, the big.matrix function doesn't work either.

```
test <- as.big.matrix(matrix(combn(x, 3)), backingfile = "abc")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.0 Gb
Error in as.big.matrix(matrix(combn(x, 3)), backingfile = "abc") : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.big.matrix'
```

Is there a way to combine these two functions together to get what I need? Are there any other ways of achieving this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using [combinadics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinadic) to generate each combination?  I think I have some R code to do this, but I'd have to dig for it.

Comment: @Josh I'm not sure I understand how combinadics is different from what I'm trying to achieve. I used the as.character(1:1344) as an example, but the reality is that my values are not continuous. If you think the R code you have might help, please post. Thanks!

Comment: @Joshua @Joris @Dirk thanks for all your suggestions. I went with Joris's approach because of time constraints (though I don't know which one is faster). I'm letting the system run for a while for all 400m lines. @Joshua, i think many people will find lots of value in your combinadic function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first find all 2-way combinations, and then just combine them with the 3d value while saving them every time. This takes a lot less memory:

```
combn.mod <- function(x,fname){
  tmp <- combn(x,2,simplify=F)
  n <- length(x)
  for ( i in x[-c(n,n-1)]){
    # Drop all combinations that contain value i
    id <- which(!unlist(lapply(tmp,function(t) i %in% t)))
    tmp <- tmp[id]
    # add i to all other combinations and write to file
    out <- do.call(rbind,lapply(tmp,c,i))
    write(t(out),file=fname,ncolumns=3,append=T,sep=",")
  }
}

combn.mod(x,"F:/Tmp/Test.txt")
```

This is not as general as Joshua's answer though, it is specifically for your case. I guess it is faster -again, for this particular case-, but I didn't make the comparison. Function works on my computer using little over 50 Mb (roughly estimated) when applied to your x.

EDIT

On a sidenote: If this is for simulation purposes, I find it hard to believe that any scientific application needs 400+ million simulation runs. You might be asking the correct answer to the wrong question here...

PROOF OF CONCEPT :

I changed the write line by `tt[[i]]<-out`, added `tt <- list()` before the loop and return(tt) after it. Then:

```
> do.call(rbind,combn.mod(letters[1:5]))
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "b"  "c"  "a" 
 [2,] "b"  "d"  "a" 
 [3,] "b"  "e"  "a" 
 [4,] "c"  "d"  "a" 
 [5,] "c"  "e"  "a" 
 [6,] "d"  "e"  "a" 
 [7,] "c"  "d"  "b" 
 [8,] "c"  "e"  "b" 
 [9,] "d"  "e"  "b" 
[10,] "d"  "e"  "c"
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a function I've written in R, which currently finds its (unexported) home in the [LSPM](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/lspm) package.  You give it the total number of items `n`, the number of items to select `r`, and the index of the combination you want `i`; it returns the values in `1:n` corresponding to combination `i`.

```
".combinadic" <- function(n, r, i) {

  # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289166(VS.71).aspx
  # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinadic

  if(i < 1 | i > choose(n,r)) stop("'i' must be 0 < i <= n!/(n-r)!")

  largestV <- function(n, r, i) {
    #v <- n-1
    v <- n                                  # Adjusted for one-based indexing
    #while(choose(v,r) > i) v <- v-1
    while(choose(v,r) >= i) v <- v-1        # Adjusted for one-based indexing
    return(v)
  }

  res <- rep(NA,r)
  for(j in 1:r) {
    res[j] <- largestV(n,r,i)
    i <- i-choose(res[j],r)
    n <- res[j]
    r <- r-1
  }
  res <- res + 1
  return(res)
}
```

It allows you to generate each combination based on the value of the lexicographic index:

```
> .combinadic(1344, 3, 1)
[1] 3 2 1
> .combinadic(1344, 3, 2)
[1] 4 2 1
> .combinadic(1344, 3, 403716544)
[1] 1344 1343 1342
```

So you just need to loop over 1:403716544 and append the results to a file.  It may take awhile, but it's at least feasible (see Dirk's answer).  You also may need to do it in several loops, since the vector `1:403716544` will not fit in memory on my machine.

Or you could just port the R code to C/C++ and do the looping / writing there, since it would be *a lot* faster.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I'll try it out and I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: lovely implementation! I had to take a good look at how it worked, but it's a gem for sure.

Comment: @Joris Thank James McCaffrey.  I found the implementation on MSDN. It honestly took me several days to wrap my brain around it and the other unexported combinatorics functions in LSPM (also from MSDN).

Comment: Great work, for anyone trying to understand how to make it work with strings you need to calculate `n0 <- length(n)`, and substitute any `n` by `n0` and at the end use `n[res]` to obtain the values of such combination.

Comment: Also, if using this to fill in a distance matrix, it basically returns values of an upper-triangular distance matrix by column

Answer (score 1):

At a first approximation, *every* algorithm trades off storage for speed.

You have hit a boundary trying to preallocate your fully enumerated combination matrix. So maybe you should try not to preallocate this matrix but to try, say,

1. If you think you need the combinations, calculate them somewhere else and store them in a simple db (or, heck, flat file) and look them up -- 9 gb saved
2. Take advantage of open source, read the code to `combn()` and modify it into a *client-server* thingy:  given a call with index number *N*, it will loop and return the *Nth* entry.  Not efficient, but possibly more easily *feasible*.

Comment: I don't want to have the matrix in memory nor do I want to really do anything with it in R. I just want to generate the values and create a flat file which then becomes an input for a mapreduce job, whevere evey line is a unique case for a simluation I'm running. I though about looking at the code for combn() and perhaps modify it to play with big.matrix, I just haven't had the time. When you suggest to calculate them somewhere else (1 above), what would you recommend?

Comment: You could even do R itself: grab the function, but instead of writing them into one big matrix, incrementally write out to file or db.